# Standalone Atmega328

Tags: batteries, atmega, servo

I am animating a small toy using three HXT900 servos controlled by a standalone ATmega328p.
Space is very tight indeed!
I am considering using two li-ion or li-poly 3.7v (700mAh) cellphone batteries; one for the ATmega and the other to power the servos separately.

I can remove and charge the batteries in a cellphone, so no charger chip is necessary.

I am also aware that the Li-ion/poly batteries should not go below a certain voltage, but believe that there is a protection circuit inbuilt which obviates the need for an external protection cct.

Does the readership think this is feasible?

Comment: What is the question? Are you asking if what you have is enough?

Comment: Well yes, I suppose so.
Will the battery drive the Servos continuously for about 10 mins for example?

Answer (score 1):

Servos operate at about 5 to 6 volts, so you can connect the two batteries in series to form a 7.4v battery, and use a regulator to step down the voltage to between 5 and 5.5 volts. You will want to use a switching regulator (or something similar - just not a linear regulator as this will overheat). I've used the 3 amp model of this regulator with success: http://www.dimensionengineering.com/DE-SWADJ.htm. Fairly small, pretty cheap. You shouldn't need a heat sink.

Batteries in series will increase the voltage, and in parallel it will increase the number of amp-hours. You didn't say how much current each servo will be pulling, so you might need a bigger (as in higher amp-hour rating) battery. Take a look at this one: http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10471

After being stepped down by the regulator, this 5 to 5.5 volt output can be safely connected to the microcontroller to power it.

As for additional components, I'm no expert but I think you will need a crystal to drive the clock, decoupling capacitors to smooth the power (switching regulators are noisy), and probably a few other passives. I'm assuming you don't need Arduino-style programming functionality (i.e. USB programming), so you will need to buy an AVR programmer.

Comment: Thanks for reply SC.

The servos are power hungry and may pull 500-700mA or even more! So I suspect the battery will not last that long. I also worry that the battery may get 'slightly' warm:-)
By having a separate battery for the Atmega I hope to reduce interference from the servos.
I am using these batteries for their slim fit.

Comment: Any interference from the servos will be mitigated by the decoupling capacitors (as long as you put them right at the power inputs of the chip).